# Set page title in client component with NextJS's app router

Tags: next.js

I need to set a page title in a client component using NextJS's app router.

You cant use a metadata object in a client component, it throws an error:

```
import { Metadata } from "next";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "My title",
};
```

The Head component doenst error but also doesnt work:

```
import Head from "next/head";

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div className={"flex"}>
      <Head>
        <title key="title">My title</title>
      <Head>
```

Comment: any solution for this??